# Spring Data Rest API dependance and problems in n-tier

Tags: java, spring-data-rest

I like what Spring Data Rest provides out of the box but I see a few design problems that I'd like to address prior to using it for my next project:

1. SDR's main drift seems to be to expose data repositories straight out over MVC. I consider this to be a flawed approach because you end up tying your API to whatever your DB says. Consider this in your DB:

   `TABLE customer {
     fullName TEXT
   }`

Under spring data rest that will end up being exported to for eg:
{
   "fullname": "foo"
}

now suppose I decide to change my DB table to say:

   `TABLE customer {
      firstName TEXT
      lastName TEXT
   }`

that is, I split the field in two: suddenly my client-facing API has been modified. If I had better control I'd be delivering ApiCustomer object which contains:

`ApiCustomer{
    String fullname;
}`

and during mapping I get the chance to say that fullName is now firstName + lastName leaving my customer-facing API unchanged. Is it possible for me to hook into a conversion process so as to make sure this doesn't occur?

2. Let's say I want to develop an N-tier application where I have an MVC module that handles all HTTP/REST/validation bits and a core module which has links to DB. The two modules live in different JVMs and are connected to each other with, for eg, rabbitmq or whatever.

Unless I'm missing something, Spring Data Rest wants me to place repositories in the MVC module where I do not have any database components at all. I cannot figure out a way to tell it: these are the repositories you will have somewhere else, whenever you need to do something on them, ask me first so I get a chance to proxy to the Core module.

Am I going down the wrong path here?

Comment: Your reasoning is wrong... You tie it to your model NOT your database. Also you can simply tell Spring Data REST what and how to expose using [projections and excerpts](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts). So in short I suggest a read of the reference guide.

Comment: Thanks, though won't I need to have Repository interfaces in the MVC module too (which in turn would require me to have an implementation provider like JPA?)

Comment: No... They need to be there as a dependency else there isn't much to expose is there...

Comment: That's my point - it's not nice that it assumes that the repositories have to be within that module. My MVC does not care about DBs at all, why should it drag in jpa to the mix when it's meant to be dealing with HTTP requests only? If only it gave me a hook where I can say: yes assume this repository exists and here's what it will look like, then I can take control by proxing to a different JVM or whatever.

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you are saying? Why would your web need that? Only the module that contains Spring Data Rest because that well uses the repository metadata for exposure to the web. Also it has nothing to do with JPA it has to do with repositories it will work for MongoDB, Redis etc. as well. It works for all types of Spring Data repos

Comment: What I require is that it works with *remoted* Spring Data repos - the repo interfaces are *not* living on the web module's classpath. Currently, component scanning determines what's available to expose: what I require is to tell it that the interfaces are available, just that the implementation is not on your classpath. Put differently, I want to be able to put in a proxy for all Repository interfaces (so I can intercept and remote any calls I care about) and have Spring data rest recognise those as valid interfaces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89074/discussion-between-wwadge-and-m-deinum).

Answer (score 0):

This new spring project seems to fit the bill very well for this:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/keyvalue/docs/current/reference/html/